# Problemas em retornar um array em arduino

Tags: funções, arduino, return

Não estou conseguindo retornar o `array` do seguinte código:

```
void loop() {
  if(tem_msg){
    lcd.clear();              // <-- limpa o cursor e retorna ele pra linha 1 e coluna 1
    lcd.print(msg[indice]);   // <-- printa a msg do indice
    tem_msg = false;          // <-- limpa a flag da msg
  }

  ent_1 = analogRead(A0);
  if(ent_1 == 0){
   funcaoMsg();
  }

}

**void** funcaoMsg(){
 mensagem[]={true, 2};
}
```

Como faço para retornar o `array` desse código?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).